# image load not with canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to load an image on webpage, but image does not display.

This is the code in `<body>` tag

```
<canvas height="400" width=""400"" id="c"></canvas>

                <script>
                    var c=document.querySelector("#c");
                    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

                    var image=new Image();
                    image.onload=function(){
                        console.loge("Loaded image");
                        ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,c.width,c.height);

                    }
                    image.src="barn.jpg";
                </script>
```

Comment: There are a few bugs in your code: 1. Your canvas width has too many quotes. 2. `console.loge` should be `console.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, but as @markE commented, there are some syntax errors, which I wouldn't call bugs. The way I see it is that you need to put the `image.src="barn.jpg";` *before* the **image.onload();** function. This is how I would make the code:

---

```
<canvas height="400" width="400" id="c"></canvas>
<script>
    var c=document.querySelector("#c");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

    var image=new Image();
    image.src="barn.jpg";

    image.onload=function(){
        console.log("Loaded image");
        ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,c.width,c.height);

    }
</script>
```

**Note:** I am not entirely sure why you didn't just use `document.getElementById("c");` instead of `document.querySelector("#C");`